# ActiveDocument.Path returning ""

Tags: vba, ms-word

Had a *.dotm working fine & today is first time I've run it in a while. Now throwing an error.

Looking into it & for some reason hen I run`Debug.Print(ActiveDocument.Path)`. it is returning `""`. I have tested a few variations on empty documents (but saved) and these are the results I'm getting:

`Debug.Print(ActiveDocument.Name)` Result: `"Document1"`

`Debug.Print(ActiveDocument.FullName)` Result: `"Document1"` (although I expected this to also include the filepath).

When I sub out `ActiveDocument.Path` with a hardcoded string it works fine again.

I'm on a corporate IT system, is there a chance that access to the path has been denied? How can I check this & are there any workarounds??

Comment: They are definitely saved? What it is returning is what gets returned if you run those three properties on a new document. Maybe you have a copy of word stuck open and its getting that one from the activedocument?

Comment: Definitely saved. I've edited the question to clarify the issue a bit better. Now illustrates the results returned when I run Debug.print on each of those properties.

Comment: Perhaps a windowless Word doc has been opened and that's the actual ActiveDocument. It's always easier to supply an answer when you post your code.

Comment: Looks to me like you might need to reinstall Word, or, maybe, MS Office all together on this machine. I say this because the "FullName" and "Path" properties are not being returned, but they certainly should be. If your VBA code compiles without erring out then these object properties are recognized, so it's not an issue of Project References. The object is there but its properties are not "populated"... this is not a VBA problem, I think.

Comment: Document1 is the type of name you get when you double click a template (.dotm) file.  If you want to open the template for editing you have to go through the File.Open dialog.  You may not be seeing a path because the Document1 has not been saved at the time you are inspecting the full name.

Comment: I agree with Freeflow. BTW "When I sub out..." is not at all clear what you mean.